# Is it possible to edit a migration in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database called MembershipType which contains 2 fields.

I added a new field call 'Name'. I wanted to hard-code the data in to the database by using a SQL query.

I wanted to seed data into the column 'Name' which is the other column is already filled with. Is that possible or not?

Comment: just add a default value on the field in your migration file

Comment: Do you mean just key-in the data into the database without using code?

Comment: no, what I mean is that when we create a migration there is an option to set the default value in it. can please mention your migration file in your question.

Comment: Oh, i see i think i know what you are saying thanks

Comment: ok let me know if its solve your problem